# Thread effectiveness for graphical applications

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, gpu, libgdx

Let's say I'm creating lighting for a scene, using my own shaders. It is a good example of a thing that might be divided between many threads, for example by dividing scene into smaller scenes and rendering them in separate threads.

1. Should I divide it into threads manually, or is graphic library going to somehow automatically divide such operations? Or is it library dependent (i'm using libgdx, which appears to be using OpenGL). Or maybe there is other reason why I should leave it alone in one thread?
2. If I should take care of dividing workload between threads manually, how many threads should I use? Is the number of threads in such situation graphic card dependent or processor dependent?

Comment: How many GPUs ya got?

Comment: One. Still, It is possible the user of the application would have more than one in SLI, or GPU with multiple chips.

Comment: The graphics card has its own scheduling and thread model.  It has nothing to do with OS threads.  Hardware OpenGL implementations fully take advantage of hardware parallelism in the GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL does not support multi-threaded rendering since an OpenGL context is only valid on the thread which it is created.

What you could do to potentially gain some performance is separate your update logic and your rendering logic into separate threads. However, you can not leverage multiple threads for OpenGL rendering.